# Convert hour UTC time to local time moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I wanted to convert "1" being UTC time to local time like this:

const selectedHour = "1";
const result = moment(selectedHour, "hh").local().format('hh');

But I get "1" itself;

Need your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should treat `1` as UTC. In order to do this, moment has a constructor which treats input as UTC date.

Be careful about formats. `h` represents 12 hour time without leading zero, `hh` with leading zero. `HH` is for 24 hour time. Check https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

```js
const selectedHour = "1";

const result = moment.utc(selectedHour, "h").local().format('hh');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```